# Group by, aggregate, include separate column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

Here's my data:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({
    'accnt' : [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105],
    'gender' : [0, 1 , 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 , 0, 1, 0],
    'date' : pd.to_datetime(["2019-01-01 00:10:21", "2019-01-05 00:09:18", "2019-01-05 00:09:30", "2019-02-05 00:05:12", "2019-04-01 00:08:46",
             "2019-04-01 00:11:31", "2019-02-06 00:01:39", "2019-01-26 00:15:14", "2019-01-21 00:12:36", "2019-03-01 00:09:31"]),
    'value' : [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 5, 2, 6, 48, 96]
                })
```

Which is:

```
   accnt    date                gender  value
0   101  2019-01-01 00:10:21       0    10
1   102  2019-01-05 00:09:18       1    20
2   103  2019-01-05 00:09:30       0    30
3   104  2019-02-05 00:05:12       1    40
4   105  2019-04-01 00:08:46       0    50
5   101  2019-04-01 00:11:31       0    5
6   102  2019-02-06 00:01:39       1    2
7   103  2019-01-26 00:15:14       0    6
8   104  2019-01-21 00:12:36       1    48
9   105  2019-03-01 00:09:31       0    96
```

I want to do the following:
- Group by `accnt`, include `gender`, take latest `date` as `latest_date`, count number of transactions as `txn_count`; resulting in:

```
  accnt  gender         latest_date        txn_count
   101      0       2019-04-01 00:11:31         2
   102      1       2019-02-06 00:01:39         2
   103      0       2019-01-26 00:15:14         2
   104      1       2019-02-05 00:05:12         2
   105      0       2019-04-01 00:08:46         2
```

In R, I can do this using `group_by` and `summarise` from `dplyr`:

```
foo %>% group_by(accnt) %>% 
summarise(gender = last(gender), most_recent_order_date = max(date), order_count = n()) %>% data.frame()
```

I'm taking `last(gender)` to include it, since `gender` is the same throughout for any `accnt`, I can take `min`, `max` or `mean` instead also.

How can I do the same in python using pandas?

I've tried:

```
foo.groupby('accnt').agg({'gender' : ['mean'],
                          'date': ['max'],
                          'value': ['count']}).rename(columns = {'gender' : "gender",
                                                                 'date' : "most_recent_order_date",
                                                                 'value' : "order_count"})
```

But this leads to "extra" column names. I'd also like to know what is the best way to include a non-aggregation column like `gender` in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R `summarise` will equal to `agg` , `mutate` equal to `transform`

The reason why you have multiple index in columns : Since you pass the function call with `list` , which means you can do something like `{'date':['mean','sum']}`

```
foo.groupby('accnt').agg({'gender' : 'first',
                          'date': 'max',
                          'value': 'count'}).rename(columns = {'date' : "most_recent_order_date",
                                                                 'value' : "order_count"}).reset_index()
Out[727]: 
   accnt most_recent_order_date  order_count  gender
0    101    2019-04-01 00:11:31            2       0
1    102    2019-02-06 00:01:39            2       1
2    103    2019-01-26 00:15:14            2       0
3    104    2019-02-05 00:05:12            2       1
4    105    2019-04-01 00:08:46            2       0
```

---

Some example : Here I called two function same time for one `columns` , which means there should be have two `level` of `index` to make sure the out columns names do not have duplicated

```
foo.groupby('accnt').agg({'gender' : ['first','mean']})
Out[728]: 
      gender     
       first mean
accnt            
101        0    0
102        1    1
103        0    0
104        1    1
105        0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response. Here's a solution I found.

```
# Pandas Operations
foo = foo.groupby('accnt').agg({'gender' : ['mean'],
                                'date': ['max'],
                                'value': ['count']})

# Drop additionally created column names from Pandas Operations
foo.columns = foo.columns.droplevel(1)

# Rename original column names
foo.rename( columns = { 'date':'latest_date',
                        'value':'txn_count'}, 
            inplace=True)
```

If you'd like to include an additional non aggregate column, you can simply append a new column to the grouped foo dataframe.